# Matching from a set of words

Tags: regex, go

I need to find a regexp (in go) to match words from a word set like `(sun|flower)` but only separated words, for example `"sun flower"` should match both words, but `"sunflower"` or `"sun-flower"` should not.

My first approach was to use the regex `\b(sun|flower)\b` but for this case `"sun-flower"` both words are matching.

Trying with a regex like `(?:^|\s+)(sun|flower)(?:\s+|$)`,  `"sun-flower"` is not matching which is ok but when testing with `"sun flower"` only sun is matching.

I've seen that others languages like java or python have lookahead and lookbehind assertions and we can achieve this with a regex like

```
(?:^|(?<= ))(sun|flower)(?:(?= )|$)
```

But in go that assertions are not supported, so I wonder if there is a way to achieve this with go

Answer (score 1):

Remove dashes, then use the alternation wrapped in word boundaries:

```
\b(sun|flower)\b
```

Comment: Yep, that was my first approach

Comment: oh, so "sun-flower" must not match, it implies that the dash is *not* a word separators, so can you just remove all dashes from the input before testing with the regex?

Comment: That is not possible because I need to keep "sun-flower". All matches will be removed ;)

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer previously but then thought better.

Look-aheads and other such "fancy" things I have been able to get by without by using multiple passes on my data.

For example, why not simply split the string using whitespace and *then* looking for either sun or flower in the resultant slice of strings? the regexp involved would be much shorter (simply `^(sun|flower)$`), and the code would be easier to maintain.

Comment: Sure, That would be a possible solution but it is not the intention of the question. I spent a little time trying to do this with regex and with Java at least it is possible using those fancy things, and I would like to know which is the alternative in go using regex. But you are right, that is a possible solution.

Comment: @rvillablanca Your hope for lookaheads in Golang got me curious, and I looked around. alas, a quick google search yields sadness when it comes to golang and lookaheads :( https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18868

Comment: Yep, the problem is how to implement those features efficiently while maintaining O(n)